# What do I need for integrating XMPP into Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

Here's what I have so far.

1. XMPP Server - Ejabberd or [Vine](http://www.getvines.org/)
2. XMPP Library in Rails - [Blather](https://github.com/adhearsion/blather)
3. XMPP Library on Client - Strophe.js

Is this what I need to integrate chat into my rails app?

EDIT: from the creator of Vine.
"It's probably safer to use ejabberd, since its a more full-featured server than vines."

Answer (score 3):

I would have add a comment but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet.

If you want to do your chat client side, Strophe is recommended. If you want to store some conversations, you'll do it server-side, but not 'rails server'-side, you should do it 'xmpp server'-side : Ejabberd should store your old messages, romm topics or your contact list. It's his job.

Blather could be usefull to make rails communicate with your xmpp-server. Typical use cases could be making server to server communication, or creating an xmpp bot to interact in your chat : it could be asking questions for a game or managing the room to kick flooders.

Answer (score 0):

You need only a server and a client library. So you go either with Blather or Strophe.
Strophe is a JavaScript library and runs on the web browser, while blather is a rails library and runs on your server.
When you want to create a web chat then I think you should go with Strophe.

Comment: I am trying to mimic facebook chat, and I thought I needed Blather to store the chat's inside the database.  That way, the chats can be stored for later viewing/searching.  Is this correct?

Comment: @wanab33ninja how have you ended up implemented your chat? I'm trying to do the same, and I have no idea on where to store them or how to configure the xmpp openfire/ ejabberd.

Comment: I completely gave up @BogdanDaniel! Today, I would spin it as a completely different service.  I was young and naive back then :)