# how to implement chat with ruby on rails web app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, chat

I would like to implement chat similar to fb with rails, where also emails of users will be filtered out.

what is the best solution?

How does the email filtering work, jquery chat

Answer (score 0):

check out [XMPP4R](https://github.com/ln/xmpp4r). Actually there are may, just google for keywords **XMPP** and **Jabber** with **rails**

There is a whole website dedicated to [XMPP protocol](http://xmpp.org/). Do spend some time reading it

Someone already asked a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326439/what-do-i-need-for-integrating-xmpp-into-rails)